# Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

80% of all messages sent across the internet are a spam. 87.25% of spam messages contain the word 'free'. 1% of non spam messages contain 'free'.

What is the probability(the message has the word free | it is a spam message)

Would I need to use the condition probability formula to work this out?

I got the answer as 0.8725 - can somebody confirm if this is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $87.25\%$ because that is the fraction of spam messages that contain the word 'free'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are completely correct. If you were looking for another way to do this rather than the conditional probability you could also draw a tree and see it that way. Either way you will get $87.25$%.

**Edit: (For question in comment)**

Probability that a message is spam and contains the word free: $$P(\text{Spam}\cap\text{Free})=P(\text{Free}|\text{Spam})\cdot P(\text{spam})$$ $$P(\text{Spam}\cap\text{Free})=.8725\cdot .8=.698$$

Probability that a message has the word free: $$P(\text{Has the word free})=P(\text{Free}|\text{Not Spam})+P(\text{Free}|\text{Spam})$$$$P(\text{Has the word free})=.002+.698=.7$$

Comment: No, the formula is not correct; that should be: $$P(\text{Has the word free)} = P(\text{Free}\cap\text{Not spam}) + P(\text{Free}\cap\text{Spam})$$ But the numbers are right though.

Comment: Since they are independent variables doesn't $P(a|b)=P(a)P(b)=P(a\cap b)$?

Comment: First, they are not independent; second, if they were independent, then $P(a\mid b) = P(a)$.

Comment: Oh wow, I have no idea what I was doing on this problem. I'll have to look back over it. I'm on my mobile now so it'll be later, but Thanks for catching my mistake!